# Can you please help me with a powershell script to ping a list of servers from a selected source

Tags: powershell, ping, telnet

Can you please help me with a PowerShell script to ping a list of servers from a selected source and provide the output of failed and successful in CSV format

Can you please help me with a PowerShell script to ping a list of servers from a selected source and provide the output of failed and successful in CSV format?

tried the below batch script but a blank ping.txt came up.

```
@echo off
type NUL > ping.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%D IN (import.csv) DO (
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%S IN (import.csv) DO (
ping `%%D` -l 0 -S `%%S` >> ping.txt
))
```

Comment: Can you please let us know what you've already tried and how it failed?

Comment: @echo off
type NUL > ping.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%D IN (import.csv) DO (
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%S IN (import.csv) DO (
ping `%%D` -l 0 -S `%%S` >> ping.txt
))

Comment: no output, just a blank ping.txt as output

Comment: Add it [to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74532087/edit) :)

Comment: but I will like if a PowerShell script can be created for this rather than bat

Comment: Then _update your post with that information_ :)

Comment: Have a look at [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection)

Comment: Something like `(import-csv import.csv).hostname | test-connection -count 1`